# Could you suggest any of JADE's example?

Tags: agents-jade, repast-simphony

Recently I'm eager to learn Repast Symphony and JADE after acquiring Netlogo.

However, there were not enough examples to illustrate how this actually works on the Internet. And official documentation was not that helpful in enhancing understanding of it.

If I'm able to see the example, it would be great help in my study.

Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reccomend the following resources:

1. This is a youtube video which may help with the inital setup of the JADE platform but really not much else.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dFx1_XBGVI
2. Here are the examples which you mentioned weren't very helpful in your case.
   http://jade.tilab.com/documentation/tutorials-guides/
3. I personally used the book(http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470057475.html). It is rather pricey but it was very useful in understanding the JADE platform and its tools.

I hope this helps.